# How large is the map in New World?

Tags: new-world

How many square miles/kilometers does the land mass of New World occupy? Including all areas/territories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on various guides and forums ([here](https://updatedgamer.com/2021/09/finding-your-ideal-settlement-in-new-world/), [here](https://www.gamepressure.com/editorials/previews/new-world-preview-why-is-amazon-making-an-mmo/zc246), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/newworldgame/comments/fblrw7/what_about_mounts/)<sup>1</sup>), the map size of New World at launch is roughly 40 square kilometers (or ~15.5 square miles).

---

<sup>1</sup> This reddit thread states the developers themselves stated the map size is 40 square kilometers, but I cannot find any video or Q&A to back this up

Comment: Good answer! It seems like all of these sources are from the Beta release of the game, is the area of the map the same since then?

Comment: @Flats I haven’t seen anything that has said otherwise ‍♂️

Comment: Fair enough for me lol